# telerik asyncUpload not working in IE9

Tags: asp.net, upload, telerik

I'm trying to use telerik asyncUpload, it works fine in all browsers but in IE9, I should turn on compatibility mode in order to see my file upload process after I select the file, but in this demo site (http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/upload/examples/async/webmail/defaultcs.aspx) it works fine in IE9 without need to turn on compatibility mode, how can I do something like this demo site for IE9?

when I select  a file in browsers other than IE9, file name is displayed and a small progress bar showing file upload is also displayed, also a small remove button appears beside file name, but in IE9 I see nothing after select my file, I should turn on compatibility mode, I hope this description is helpful, but in demo site, everything works fine for all browsers, what am I missing?

also I'm going to store my images in database, do I need to perform postback? where I my files stored?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this article that sounds similar to the problem your having.

http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/aspnet-ajax/async-upload/select-button-with-not-show-the-select-files-window.aspx

Basically there has been a certain problem with the Flash module in IE9, which is related to the Flash. Which could be why your not seeing anything in IE9.

If this is the issue they suggest disabling the flash module with the following JS:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
Telerik.Web.UI.RadAsyncUpload.Modules.Flash.isAvailable = function () { return false; }
</script>
```